# What are the objects drawn at the start of The Warlock's Hairy Heart in Tales of Beedle the Bard?

Tags: harry-potter, object-identification, the-tales-of-beedle-the-bard

*The Tales of Beedle the Bard* has a small drawing from J.K. Rowling at the start of each story.  I found some of these difficult to interpret.

The most puzzling one is the drawing at the start of ***“The Warlock's Hairy Heart”*** which shows what looks like an assortment of objects: a stringed instrument (lute or similar), a book, a door key, a goblet with some dark liquid spilling out of it, and a cross-shaped object (perhaps a dagger).

**What is this drawing supposed to depict, and what is its significance related to this story?**

[image]

Comment: Rowling also drew [a lot of illustrations](http://imgur.com/a/zW3M5) which weren't included in the published book.

Comment: @ibid - That's a much better collection. Still scans, but much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're simply an assortment of objects that are referred to in the text of the story. There doesn't appear to be a specific theme.

From left to right;

- A book of poetry
- A lute
- The key to the Warlock's dungeon
- Fine wine
- The silver dagger that the Warlock inadvertently kills himself with.

---

> *The table was laden with silver and gold, bearing **the finest wines** and
>   most sumptuous foods. Minstrels strummed on **silk-stringed lutes** and
>   sang of a love their master had never felt. The maiden sat upon a
>   throne beside the warlock, who spake low, **employing words of
>   tenderness he had stolen from the poets,** without any idea of their
>   true meaning.*

and

> *The warlock smiled, and told her that she need not fear on that score.
>   Bidding her follow, he led her from the feast, and down to **the locked
>   dungeon** where he kept his greatest treasure.*

and

> *Before the horror-struck eyes of his guests, the warlock cast aside
>   his wand, and seized **a silver dagger.** Vowing never to be mastered by
>   his own heart, he hacked it from his chest.*

Comment: I always assumed that it was a key to the chest containing the heart.

Comment: @ibid - The heart was in an "*enchanted crystal casket*" which he opens with his wand. There's no indication, however, that the "*locked dungeon*" was anything other than a simple locked door, one which required a key to open.

Comment: I guess that makes. The key was always puzzling, because although never explicitly mentioned in the text, Rowling seemed to be [oddly fixated on it](http://i.imgur.com/Jqt3nwK.png), as if it an essential element to the story.

Comment: @ibid - Possibly it had greater significance in an earlier version of the story.

Comment: Assuming you have an extra £500,000 or so, [you'll soon  be able to find out.](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/11/04/for-sale-unique-bejewelled-beedle-the-bard-given-by-jk-rowling-t/)